# Far dates get converted into datetime.datetime object instead of datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, spyder

I have written following code:

```
date_format = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%b-%Y") if x!=0 else np.nan

input_file['Business date']    = input_file['Business date'].fillna(0).apply(date_format)
input_file['Date of the Flow'] = input_file['Date of the Flow'].fillna(0).apply(date_format)
```

When I take unique of "Business date" column, it shows output as:

```
input_file["Business date"].unique()
Out[61]: array(['2019-02-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-02-18T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

And for "Date of the Flow":

```
input_file["Date of the Flow"].unique()
Out[64]: 
array([nan, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 18, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 24, 0, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2028, 7, 15, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2122, 12, 19, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2026, 11, 28, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Why it behaves such? Also note that the "Date of the Flow" column has dates of year 2505. If I remove those date, it gives output same as "Business date" i.e. dtype='datetime64[ns]'

Comment: Hi, can you please provide us some examples of your original input data, i.e. items from `input_file["Business date"]` and `input_file['Date of the Flow']` before applying the `date_format` function?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It seems like Time Series in Python has limitation/range. Because of which my date in year 2505 was coming in datetime format and not in timestamp. Found it in following link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:

```
In [90]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[90]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [91]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[91]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```